# В manjaro менеджер пакетов Pacman не устанавливает и не удаляет приложения

Tags: manjaro

Pacman при попытке установить или удалить приложение имеющееся в его базе,выдает ошибку "Ошибка авторизации"

Answer (score 0):

для установки и удаления пакетов `pacman` нужно запускать с правами суперпользователя

```
sudo pacman ...
```